# Cómo enviar información entre 2 páginas?

Tags: php, post

Estoy buscando la manera de enviar información entre 2 páginas. No de la manera `www.foo.com/pagina1.php` a `www.foo.com/pagina2.php`
sino de la manera `www.foo.com/pagina1.php` a `www.foo2.com/pagina1.php`.

He estado leyendo mucho sobre esto, pero la mayoría de las respuestas que he encontrado son para la primera situación, donde me dicen que use variables de sesión para el envío de la información de manera segura.

El caso es que quiero enviar información (Nombre, Teléfono y una imagen) de una página a otra, haciendo uso de POST, pero sin usar formularios en html (porque supongo que es menos seguro hacerlo así, igual si alguien me puede corregir en esto, se los agradecería).

He conseguido hacer el envío de información con el `FORM` de html:

```
<form action="http://localhost/prueba/pruebaDom2/index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $arr["id"] ?>" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="<?php echo $arr["nombre"] ?>" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="corr" id="corr" value="<?php echo $arr["correo"] ?>" hidden>
  <button type="submit" id="enviar" hidden></button>
</form>
```

y simplemente lo imprimo del otro lado

```
<h1><?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $_POST["nom"]; ?></h1>
<h1><?php echo $_POST["corr"]; ?></h1>
```

Ahora mi pregunta:
Es posible enviar la información con PHP puro? De qué manera es más seguro hacerlo? y además, cómo puedo hacer el envío de la imagen?

Comment: Si es posible, de hecho tiene un nombre (web services). Puedes generar un post de javascript, html o php hacia cualquier URL. El único problema en el caso de HTML o javascript en el navegador es que la url destino debe permitir solicitudes de orígenes cruzados, si lo haces desde PHP no tienes ese problema. Sobre la seguridad, el problema es exactamente el mismo si es que fuera para un sitio o 2, o si el post es generado por un form en html o es envíado por código.

Comment: Te agradezco! y sobre la imagen? cómo puedo hacer el envío? estaba pensando en poner un input de tipo file y ahí meter el archivo(la imagen está guardada en el servidor) pero no se si eso vulnere de alguna manera el sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar un POST desde PHP hacia otra página puedes usar [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) (igualmente existen otras formas de hacerlo)

Un ejemplo, podría ser algo como esto.

```
<?php

$file = realpath('imagen.png');

// URL destino
$url = '......';

// Datos a enviar, incluyendo el archivo
$data = array(
    'id' => 1221,
    'nom' => 'Un nombre',
    'corr' => 'yussef@elmascapo.com',
    'file' => new CURLFile($file, mime_content_type($file), basename($file))
);


$ch = curl_init($url);

//seteamos la petición
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

// ejecutamos
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $response = curl_error($ch);
}
// cerramos la conexioón
curl_close($ch);


echo $response;

?>
```

Creo que el código es bastante autoaplicativo, básicamente tiene 3 partes importante

- Asignación de los datos a enviar en un array `$data`
- Configuración del cURL
- Ejecución del cURL

Comment: Muchas gracias! he estado jugueteando con el código que me pasaste, y noto 2 cosas: la primera, no está enviando la imagen. estoy haciendo un `var_dump()` en el archivo destino y en el array no aparece el archivo. y 2: en la URL aun aparece `foo.com/pagina1.php` a pesar de que el body que se muestra es el de `foo2.com/pagina1.php` Es normal?

Comment: @ArieesAndromeda Estuve probando y al parecer si había un problema, he cambiado el código para que lo revises. Agregue la función `realpath` para obtener la ruta y el tipo mime para el CURFile. Por otro lado, el punto 2 de tu comentario no lo he entendido

Comment: si, yo también estuve haciendo pruebas con lo de la imagen y parece que ya pude hacer el envío. En el segundo punto me refería a que hago el envío de la info desde la `página1.php` a `pagina2.php`, y toda la información y los procesos con ella la hago desde `pagina2.php`, pero en la URL sigue apareciendo la ruta de la `pagina1.php`.

Comment: @ArieesAndromeda  en la url del navegador?

Comment: Si, a pesar de que en CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL me devuelve la ruta a la que quiero hacer el header, la url del navegador no cambia

Comment: Es que el navegador realiza una petición a `pagina1` y la respuesta la obtiene de esa misma página. Lo que haga `pagina1` dentro (ir a una base de datos, leer un archivo o ir a hacer post a otra página) es transparente para el navegador. Si tu necesitas que vaya a otra URL luego, seguramente tendrás que hacer una redirección, algo como `header("Location: https//foo.com/pagina2.php")`

Comment: okay, pero una vez que haga el header, podré seguir usando las variables `$_POST["id"]...`? ese es el detalle.

Comment: Puedes hasta el final del script PHP, es decir hasta que le respondes al navegador. Luego al navegador lo enviaste a otro sitio, así que a menos que vuelva ya no tienes nada que hacer.

Comment: no entiendo como esto puede ser tan complicado si en html con un simple form basta jajajaja ya en última instancia: sabes como enviar imágenes mediante el post de HTML? no imagenes subidas por el usuario, sino una imagen que yo tenga en el servidor

Comment: @ArieesAndromeda Es que hay algo raro en el asunto o yo no entiendo lo que quieres hacer, o tu no entiendes como la web. Porque puedes colocar en el `action` del `form` la ruta de la página2 y ya- El código que te he puesto usa una imagen guardada en el servidor

Comment: @ArieesAndromeda En todo caso recuerdo que para subir un archivo en un formulario debes colocar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data` en el `form`